# calculating prime numbers (streams and lambdas)

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I wrote the following code to get all the prime numbers from 2..n

```
private static LongStream getPrimesStream(long number) {
    return LongStream.range(2, number + 1)
            .filter(PrimeStreamTest::isPrime);
}

private static boolean isPrime(final long number) {
    return number == 2 || (number % 2 != 0 && LongStream
            .range(2, (long) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(number + 1)))
            .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0)
            .noneMatch(divisor -> number % divisor == 0)
    );
}
```

I optimized it by checking in the range of 2..sqrt(n) and filtering out the even numbers, but now I want to further optimize it by storing all previously found primes (I don't care about memory), so that I can filter out the numbers divisible by those primes, and not just the ones divisible by 2.
I know there are better solutions, but it's just an exercise on lambdas and streams.

Comment: I  believe the better optimization is to (a) change from noneMatch() to anyMatch() and negate the result (b) The filter operation you have is really  very limited to checking if the number in the range between 2..sqrt(input) is divisible by 2 and doesn't check other prime numbers like 3,5.... Instead of all these steps make the stream return as soon as the number is divisible by the 2,3,4,5,....

Comment: @Baski: why do you think that changing from `noneMatch()` to `anyMatch()` and negate the result does optimize anything?

Comment: If you want to optimize for speed at the cost of memory, implement sieve of Eratosthenes using a `BitSet`.  But, as this is an exercise in streams, you can use `getPrimesStream` inside `isPrime` to get the prime factors to test against: `return number == 2 || getPrimesStream((long) ceil(sqrt(number))).noneMatch(divisor -> number % divisor == 0);`

Comment: @Misha: in this case, it might help the performance, if `isPrime` tests for `0` and `1` (or simply `<2`) and rejects them before initiating an unnecessary Stream operation.

Comment: @Holger thanks for catching the mis information. I guess got boxed on  mental block and not reading the API doc fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but now I want to further optimize it by storing all previously found primes

Since that would require storing those values in the middle of the stream pipeline, i.e. be an intermediate operation and most stream intermediate operations should be stateless according to their docs you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job here.

Stateful ops can be implemented by extracting a stream's `Spliterator`, wrapping it into a custom one and rewrapping it into a new stream, but in this case that seems hardly appropriate considering that this would essentially be all what your stream pipeline does.

Since you're trying to run a stateful and parallelizable *compute task* you might want to look into the [fork-join framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) or [CompletableFuture](https://sebastian-millies.blogspot.de/2016/05/concurrent-recursive-function.html) instead. The former is also used as part of the parallel stream implementation and the latter make it easier to compose computations and their results.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public static boolean isPrime(final long number) {
   return LongStream.range(2,(long) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(number + 1))).noneMatch(x -> number % x == 0);
}
```

Comment: May i know why number + 1?

Comment: @JigarNaik I may be wrong. I did it just to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: Why not call noneMatch() instead of anyMatch() and a negation sign?

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky thank you for the posting. I've updated my example

Answer (score 0):

```
// check if number return true when it divided by it self and one only
IntPredicate isDivisible = index -> number % index == 0;
// test the number 
isDivisible.test(number);
// check if numbers between 2 and the provided number is prime 
return IntStream.range(2, number - 1).noneMatch(isDivisible);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same task to solve and I create the next code what is perfectly working:

```
public static int[] primes(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, n)
        .filter(p -> BigInteger.valueOf(p).isProbablePrime(50)).toArray();
}
```

With this you can filter by dividing the numbers with the founded primes.